# How can I render multiple resources in one API request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what I am trying to achieve

"Add a RESTful, read-only API to allow consumers to retrieve Questions with Answers as JSON (no need to retrieve Answers on their own). The response should include Answers inside their Question as well as include the id and name of the Question and Answer users."

So far I have my controllers set up as follows:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.all 
    render json: @users 
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: @user 
end
```

end

```
class Api::V1::QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @questions = Question.where(share: true) 
    render json: @questions
end
```

end

```
class Api::V1::AnswersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @answers = Answer.all 
    render json: @answers 
end
```

end

And my routes are set up like this however I'm sure this is not correct for what I want to achieve

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

namespace :api do
namespace :v1 do
resources :questions do
resources :answers do
resources :users
end
end
end
end

root 'welcome#index'

get 'welcome/index'
end

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
# This should actually be API as acronyms should be allcaps
module Api
  module V1
    class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /api/v1/questions
      def index
        @questions = Question.eager_load(:answers)
                             .all
        render json: @questions, include: :answers 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```ruby
# this is all you need for the stated requirements
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :questions 
  end
end
```

Comment: PS. You owe me 10% of your first paycheck if you get the job.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, I also need to render the names of the Question and Answer users. Do you know how that would be included in this?